# If $\lambda, v$ are two measures, is $\{A:v(A)=\lambda(A)\}$ a $\sigma-$algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I was trying to prove that if $\lambda, v:M\to\mathbb{R}$ are two measures where $M$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma-$algebra and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $v(I)=\lambda(I)$ for every open interval $I$, then $v=\lambda$.

I think I almost have it If I could prove they're equal on every Borel set.

It is clear that $v(U)=\lambda(U)$ for every open set $U$. In order to conclude that they're equal in Borel sets, I'd like to answer the following question:

> Is it true that $\Sigma=\{A\in M:v(A)=\lambda(A)\}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra?

I can't prove that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions (well, not even finite unions). If $A_1,A_2\in \Sigma$, should it be $A_1\cup A_2\in\Sigma$?

Comment: The result is false in the generality stated in the title. However, with some modifications, this line of reasoning can be fruitful. You may want to have a look at the $\pi\text{-}\lambda$ theorem and the monotone class theorem.

Comment: Even if $v$ and $\lambda$ are finite measures, $\Sigma=\{A\in M:v(A)=\lambda(A)\}$ is NOT closed under intersection, so it is NOT a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ramiro I think you're right when you say $\Sigma$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra always, but in this case it must be true. If the problem states correctly, $v$ must be equal to $\lambda$ and in the end $\Sigma = M$.

Comment: In this particular case, we will prove that $\Sigma=M$  and then conclude that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:
Note that this is equivalent to asking if the null sets of a measure form a sigma algebra (Consider $v - \lambda$).  The measure of a countable union of null sets is zero.

Comment: Humm... assuming $v$ or $\lambda $ are finite, then we have that $v(A)=\lambda(A)$ iff $(v - \lambda)(A)=0$.  However, it does not mean that for any $E$ measurable, if $E\subseteq A$   then $(v - \lambda)(E)=0$.  So $A$ may not be a null set of $v-\lambda$. 


In fact, $\{A \in M : v(A)=\lambda(A)\}$ may not be closed under intersections.

Comment: Oh, to me a measure is always a positive measure.  Of course it may not be true for a signed measure.

Comment: Even if $v$ and $\lambda$ are POSITIVE finite measures, we have that $v-\lambda$ is just a signed measure. So the question is NOT equivalent to asking if the null sets of (positive) measure form a $\sigma$-algebra.   

In fact,  in general, even if $v$ and $\lambda$ are positive finite measures, $\Sigma=\{A\in M:v(A)=\lambda(A)\}$ is NOT a $\sigma-$algebra.